# How to detect bottom of the page using BeautifulSoup and get to the next page?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl a web page and get every article urls. code is below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

main_url = "https://www.rfa.org/vietnamese/news/programs/story_archive?year=2006&month=1"

re = requests.get(main_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(re.text, "html.parser")
article_links = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "sectionteaser archive"})

for div in article_links:
    links = div.findAll('a')
    for a in links:
        print(a['href'])
```

above code only accomplishes the job for the first job, but there are more pages to go through. How do I detect how many more articles and get them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop whilst there is next page pagination. That can be tested for by presence of an element with class `next`. You need to increase the offset in the request by 15 each time through loop.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

n = 0

with requests.Session() as s:
    
    while True:
        
        url = f'https://www.rfa.org/vietnamese/news/programs/story_archive?year=2006&month=1&b_start:int={n*15}'
        r = s.get(url)
        soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')
        
        print([i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('.sectionteaser a > span')])
        
        if soup.select_one('.next') is None:
            break
        n+=1
```